# NEST Search metadata lost when SORT

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, .net-core, nest

I am trying to sort a search query using NEST 7.3.1. 
Without sort, the client is retrieving results, with the Total results and MaxScore in HitsMetadata object, however, adding the following Sort criteria, Total value has a maximum of 1000 items, and the Score is lost.

```
.Query(q =>
///query stuff
.Sort(s => s.Descending(f => f.CreationDate.Suffix("keyword")))
);
```

Any idea of how can I have this metadata info even if I am sorting the data?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You have to add a _score in the sort part, try this: .Query(q =>
///query stuff
.Sort(s => s.Descending(f => f.CreationDate.Suffix("keyword")))
.Sort(so => so.Field("_score", SortOrder.Descending)
);

Comment: Hello @LeBigCat , your approach works as I wanted, could you reply it? I wanted to vote your solution. Thank you a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a _score in the sort part, try this:

```
.Query(q => ///query stuff .Sort(s => s.Descending(f => f.CreationDate.Suffix("keyword"))) .Sort(so => so.Field("_score", SortOrder.Descending) );
```

Happy this worked ;)